# Can you compress AMF objects with LZMA?

Tags: actionscript-3, amf, lzma

I know Flash 11 has native support for handling LZMA compressed swfs, is there a way to use LZMA compression with AMF objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deflate()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#deflate%28%29) and [inflate()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#inflate%28%29) to get generic compression and decompression. If you want to use this to get LZMA format, you'll need to:

> create a ByteArray structured according to the compression format's
>   specification, including the appropriate metadata as well as the
>   compressed data obtained using the deflate format.

Basically, you'll have to learn the structure, write all the header information yourself, then use `deflate()`. To uncompress, you'll need to read in the header information (`readInt(), readShort` etc), then use `inflate()` on the rest to get your date back.